# Div disappear after icon mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-hover

I'm working on a ecommerce and I have a cart icon in the header. The problem is that my div with cart content disappears before I can put my mouse on, either to click on the product link or on the checkout button.

What I need: I have to be able to interact with my cart content when mouse is either over the cart icon or over the cart content.

I have the following code where class `.cart-label` is my cart icon and `#panel` is my cart content.

```
$k('.cart-label').hover(function() {
            $k('.header-cart #panel').stop().fadeIn('fast');
        },
        function() {
            $k('.header-cart #panel').stop().fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: upload the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap both the cart icon and the cart menu inside the same div. Then you only call `hide()` on the wrapper's `mouseleave` event.

```js
$('.cartIcon').mouseover(function(){
    $('.cartInner').show();
});

$('.cartWrapper').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.cartInner').hide();
});
```

```css
.cartWrapper .cartIcon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}
 
.cartWrapper .cartInner {
  display: none;
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  background: blue;
}

.cartWrapper {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cartWrapper">
    <div class="cartIcon">
      Cart icon
    </div>
    <div class="cartInner">
      Cart inner
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although it's difficult to understand what exactly is the difference between wrapping or not, I had remembered of that logic when I made a simple menu dropdown where the submenu <ul> is under a <li>. I will try that, thanks!!

Comment: It worked! Additionally, I had to set a height for the icon to avoid a blank gap between the icon and the tooltip, I think that gap was "the guy" behind the problem.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

considering your code only I can think of is your divs over lapping on the event divs you call. check the .hover event element is overlapping with hiding element. apply a border to the div and check the mouse over will affect both divs.

to better understand update the rest of the code

Comment: I will try putting a wrapper around both icon and content, as suggested, let's see what is going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for this kind of scenario you can use [mouseover()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [mouseout()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

.mouseover() is not the same as .hover(), for the same reason .mouseover() is not the same as .mouseenter().

```
$('selector').mouseover(over_function) // may fire multiple times

// enter and exit functions only called once per element per entry and exit
$('selector').hover(enter_function, exit_function)
```

Try using below code

```
$('.header-cart #panel').mouseover(function() {
     //action when mouse over 
}
$('.header-cart #panel').mouseout(function() {
       //action when mouse out
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use mouseleave instead of mouseout?